# Unable to deploy twilio connector on WSO2

Tags: wso2, twilio, esb, connector

I'm trying to upload zip file of twilio connector (from wso2 store) on WSO2 ESB , but it said the upload failed , can you help ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is the ESB version that you are using in your environment? It seems that this is connector is released only for ESB 4.9.0 and ESB 5.0.0 versions

[1]-https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/esbconnector/details/f33557eb-65c5-4119-b0cb-3b89f287dc04